# DatePicker displaying fromat/custom message in the initial state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a DatePicker as a date input in the UI. The goal is to display the date format (placeholder) or even a empty string but all I see it the current date if I don't set the value attribute.

```
<DatePicker
            format={"dd/MM/yyyy"}
            margin="normal"
            label="Date picker"
            value={undefined}
            onChange={this.handleDateChange}
          />
```

Here is demo of what I have so far.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jv4vv6y59y

Is it possible to achieve it with the Material-UI DatePicker?

Comment: Can you share an `editable` sandbox ?

Comment: ya, please share an editable code sandbox url.

Comment: @bonomi,  I have given a code-sandbox with solution, hope that solves your prob.

Comment: I love the solution Avanthika provided. You can even take a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/9yr56yqkly

Comment: It looks good, but then I won't be able to type the date instead of using the DatePicker itself

Comment: Yea. May be you can change TextFieldComponent to appropriately to fit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using DatePicker from `material-ui-pickers` package. Initially, to set it empty, you can use the `labelFunc` prop of your DatePicker.

```
<DatePicker
 format={"DD/MM/YYYY"}
 margin="normal"
 label="Date picker"
 labelFunc={this.renderLabel}
 value={this.state.date}
 onChange={this.handleDateChange}
/>
```

In the renderLabel function, check if date is valid or not. If it is not valid, leave it empty. If we do this, unless and until we choose a date through date-picker, the field will remain empty as you expect.

```
renderLabel = (date) => {
  console.log(date.isValid());
  if (date.isValid()) {
    return date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Take a look at this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vnpk655qn

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: It looks good, but then I won't be able to type the date instead of using the DatePicker itself, and also when setting the date on the DatePicker it shows with the wrong format

Comment: Umm, I'm able to type and change though. Let me check.

Comment: Any way to do this in MUI V5? LabelFunc seems to be gone.